# How to view output from print statements with Django on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am running a Django app on Elastic Beanstalk. If I put a print statement in e.g. `admin.py`, how can I see the result?

Comment: Can't see internal output, use `logging` on `admin.py` and serve logs as html page.

Answer (score -1):

You should use logging instead of print, you can look back your log anytime and filter the result depend on different level. Check this out [logging cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html)

Comment: I've been trying to do just that for a couple of hours now. How do you give it permissions for the log file?

Comment: Is not possible with prints?